# AVPlayer video freeze when seek backward

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm working on video cropper like in the Photos app.

I implemented `AVPlayer` and developed a cropper and cursor. I'm experiencing difficulties with seek video right now.

I seek video by changing cursor position and no issues while seek forward, but when I try to seek backward video is freezing for a video shows with delay.

I attached an example. There is my seek in first part and standard Photos cropper in the second part. The same video on both parts.
What issue could be?

I use seek method with tolerance values

```
let seekTime = CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(offset), timescale: 600)
await player?.seek(to: seekTime, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

where `offset` cursor position.

https://i.imgur.com/BJFWGvu.mp4